# Integrating IMU sensor into AMCL package

Tags: ros, imu, navigation, sensor-fusion, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
Is it possible to fuse IMU sensor information into AMCL package? if possible, could you please give some suggestions for implementation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263043/integrating-imu-sensor-into-amcl-package/) by [MIN LATT](https://answers.ros.org/users/30405/min-latt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The most common way that people do this is to use either [robot_pose_ekf](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_pose_ekf) or [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) (more common these days) to fuse together the IMU and odometry data, and publish the fused result as a new tf frame. Then you can specify the `~odom_frame_id` in amcl to be this new filtered frame (usually called `/odom_combined` with robot_pose_ekf and `/odom_filt` for robot_localization).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MIN LATT](https://answers.ros.org/users/30405/min-latt/) on 2017-06-05**:
Thanks for your answer.